# are there any programs beside MPD that could be run in a headless server, and autoDJ files while streaming to icecast or shoutcast?

Tags: linux, streaming, music, headless

I'm looking for a broadcasting source that could be  managed in a linux server without GUI. either with commandline, or web-based.

I need it to randomly select my audio files and stream them to  icecast/shoutcast server, and allow me to play a file at any time that i want to, so i could  stream my shows.

I have tried MPD with mpc, but  after turning the random toggle on in mpc, it stops streaming after  five hours, and i assume it hits the end of my audio files.
I have tried airtime as well, but that wouldn't AutoDJ, and i have to schedule everything manually.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very simple scripts, written in LiquidSoap, which can perform this function.  Liquidsoap is a scripting language written to meet this use case, as well as being able to script a "radio station".

In its simplest form, with around a dozen lines of code, you give it a playlist, point to where you want the stream to go (e.g., an Icecast server or local sound card), and it will either play the playlist in order or choose randomly from it.

I've set up an in-house jukebox that randomly plays songs, but also has the ability to queue songs via the web interface (it goes back to random play once the queue runs out).

Take a look at it via: http://savonet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This app sounds a big boss, lots of features...; although it sounds so complex. I'm very bad at scripting, maybe I should google and see if  I can find scripts for it. I wonder that why airtime doesn't  have autoDJ (fallback) options, while being built on liquidsoap. it's kind of understandable though because airtime is purposed toward a different thing.

Comment: Ok, now that I have seen the quickstart page, I think I can manage it if I focus on the tutorial and try practicing it. at least I can build a simple radio I guess.

Comment: If you're compiling the backend from scratch, it can be daunthing/a pain.  Installing from packages is easy.  A simple radio should only take 20 lines or so of script (fewer if you want to give up a couple features).

Answer (score 0):

In the Airtime Hacks section of the Airtime Forum is a nice little code addition for their liquidsoap script that AutoDJ's when there is nothing scheduled - complete with weighted folders, station id, jingles etc.

Its a five minute cut and paste.